# Magento 2 - As Low As Value on List Pages VAT Shown Twice

Tags: magento2

On my **category pages**, for tier priced products the tax is added twice to the add low as price:

[image: As Low As]

This file: `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml` uses the function `renderAmountMinimal()` from block `\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox`. to return the values:

```
public function renderAmountMinimal()
{
    $id = $this->getPriceId() ? $this->getPriceId() : 'product-minimal-price-' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId();

    $amount = $this->minimalPriceCalculator->getAmount($this->getSaleableItem());


    if ($amount === null) {
        return '';
    }

    return $this->renderAmount(
        $amount,
        [
            'display_label'     => __('As low as'),
            'price_id'          => $id,
            'include_container' => false,
            'skip_adjustments' => true
        ]
    );
}
```

Looking at the object returned in `$amount` the amount does seem to have added my tax twice before this object is created.

The product pages however show the amounts correctly its just category pages they seem to be wrong for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, not elegant, but it works!

```
public function renderAmountMinimal()
    {
        $id = $this->getPriceId() ? $this->getPriceId() : 'product-minimal-price-' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId();
$amount = $this->minimalPriceCalculator->getAmount($this->getSaleableItem());

        if ($amount === null) {
            return '';
        }

        $minTierPrice = $this->minimalPriceCalculator->getValue($this->getSaleableItem());
        // var_dump($minTierPrice); // work

        // var_dump($amount);
        // Nos indica lo siguiente:
        // object(Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\Base)#6089 (5) { ["amount":protected]=> float(20141.975801) ["baseAmount":protected]=> NULL ["totalAdjustmentAmount":protected]=> NULL ["adjustmentAmounts":protected]=> array(1) { ["tax"]=> float(5957.4822) } ["adjustments":protected]=> array(0) { } } Tan bajo como $20.142


        /*
        return $this->renderAmount(
            $amount,
            [
                'display_label'     => __('As low as'),
                'price_id'          => $id,
                'include_container' => false,
                'skip_adjustments' => true
            ]
        );
        */

        // var_dump($amount);                      
        // $mycustomMinPrice = round($minTierPrice);
        $mycustomMinPrice   = number_format($minTierPrice, 0, '', '.');

        return __('As low as').' $'. $mycustomMinPrice; // work        
    }
```

[image]